# What is the analogous of the describe() or info() methods for a List in Python?

Tags: python, list, info, describe

Given a list I would like a way to explore its contents.

len() will give me the number of items in the list but how I could go further than that?  E.g. get information about the classes of the objects contained in the list and their size?

This is a rather general question. If you feel I should produce some concrete example let me know.

Comment: `for item in mylist: print type(item)`

Comment: Since there can be arbitrary types in a single list in python, there really is no better way than iterating over it and checking every item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know the available attributes and methods of a list, you can print the online help:

```
help(list)
```

If you want the documentation of a method, you can do, for instance:

```
help(list.append)
```

If you want the number of items you can use [`Len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) function:

```
l = [True, None, "Hi", 5, 3.14]
print("Length of the list is {0}".format(len(l)))
# -> Length of the list is 5
```

If you want the memory size of your list reference, you can try [`sys.getsizeof`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof) function:

```
import sys

print(sys.getsizeof(l))
# -> 104
```

For the memory size of the items, just sum the individual sizes:

```
print(sum(sys.getsizeof(i) for i in l))
# -> 147
```

To list the type of each item, use the [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) function:

```
for item in l:
    print(type(item))
```

You get:

```
<class 'bool'>
<class 'NoneType'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'float'>
```